# App Engine Cloud Task keeps throwing 500 error but works when calling the URL manually

Tags: php, google-app-engine-php

The request works on my local and when calling it in the browser manually on app engine but the background tasks keeps throwing a 500 error and the default logs are useless:

2019-10-05 11:37:48.509 ICT
The request failed because the instance could not start successfully
2019-10-05 11:37:48.509 ICT
Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404.

I've ensured that I'm catching all possible exceptions but non are being thrown.

Help! I've been at this for hours. I get the feeling it is not a code problem.

I have a Google Cloud scheduler tasks that calls /start_import to create the tasks that calls /task_handler and I can see it creates the task fine, but the task itself throws the 500 error.

The strange thing is it was working before.

```
$logger->write('Log started from background process');

/**
 * This is an example of a front controller for a flat file PHP site. Using a
 * Static list provides security against URL injection by default. See README.md
 * for more examples.
 */
# [START gae_simple_front_controller]
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
     echo 'hello there';
        //require 'homepage.php';
        break;
case '/start_import':

           global $logger;

     $logger->write('Starting task');

    //code to create task that is working

     break;
   case '/task_handler':

           global $logger;

     $logger->write('Starting task');
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok issue is solved. I went back to using the default service in GAE and it worked. I was using a separate service name but considering I only have 1 service I went back to the default.

Not tested but you may have to add the service name when creating the task? Which is not documented anywhere.